# string comparison find() in jquery isnt working with <

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I am playing with xml on client side. below is my XML.

```
<ItemList>
    <Row ID="" Name="-- Select a Item --" GrpID="" Flag=""/>
    <Row ID="S5"  Name="Item 1" GrpID="G7" Flag="0"/>
    <Row ID="S6"  Name="Item 2" GrpID="G7" Flag="0"/>
    <Row ID="S7"  Name="Item 3" GrpID="G7" Flag="0"/>
    <Row ID="S85" Name="Item 4" GrpID="G7" Flag="0"/>
    <Row ID="S5"  Name="Item 11" GrpID="G4" Flag="0"/>
    <Row ID="S13" Name="Item 5" GrpID="G7" Flag="0"/>
    <Row ID="S14" Name="Item 6" GrpID="G7" Flag="0"/>
    <Row ID="S15" Name="Item 7" GrpID="G7" Flag="0"/>
    <Row ID="S16" Name="Item 8" GrpID="G7" Flag="0"/>
    <Row ID="S17" Name="Item 9" GrpID="G7" Flag="0"/>
    <Row ID="S12" Name="Item 12" GrpID="G4" Flag="0"/>
    <Row ID="S22" Name="Item 22" GrpID="" Flag="0"/>
    <Row ID="S25" Name="Item 26" GrpID="" Flag="0"/>
</ItemList>
```

I have to assign items with (GrpID=G7 and ID<'S5') OR (GrpID is '')

```
$(xmlItems).find("Row[GrpID='7'][ID<'S82'],[GrpID='']")
```

Where am I doing wrong. I could get with the below.

```
$(xmlItems).find("Row[GrpID='7'][ID='S85'],[GrpID='']")
```

the problem "=" is working and "<" is not working for Item ID (strings) comparison.

Comment: `<` is not supposed to work with string comparison

Comment: Indeed, it is not supposed to work in the first place. There is no *Attribute Is Less Than* selector in CSS either.

Comment: You may want to look into XPath instead https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Introduction_to_using_XPath_in_JavaScript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The return statement in @AnttiHaapala should be adjusted slightly for the code to work. Please see the modified version below:

```
$filtered = $(xmlItems).find("Row[GrpID='G7']").filter(
    function (index, element) {
        return $(element).attr('ID') < 'S5';
    }
)
.add( $(xmlItems).find( 'row[GrpID=""]' ) );
```

This is because `ID` is an attribute of `row`. Since element is an iterator for `row`, you want to grab it's `ID` attribute like this:

```
$(element).attr( 'ID' );
```

Comment: How do add the other condition for items with no grp id. If I am adding next to End, the delegate/function is getting applied to those without grp id

Answer (score 1):

Jquery uses CSS selectors; the syntax does not support matching with `<` or `>`. You need to do this using the [`jQuery.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/#filter-function), for example:

```
$filtered = $(xmlItems).find("Row[GrpID='G7']").filter(
    function (index, element) {
        return element.ID < 'S5';
    }
);
```

However notice that the string comparison still might not do what you mean - this is not a numeric comparison and `'S11'` < `'S2'` is true.

Comment: + [CSS attribute selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors)

Comment: I believe `return element.ID < 'S5';` should be `return $(element).attr('ID') < 'S5';`. What do you think @AnttiHaapala?